# Как сделать отдельную страницу для каждой категории?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Имеется магазин на WP Woocommerce, сейчас все товары выводятся в основной странице "shop" разбитые по категориям.
URL страницы товара имеет вид "/shop/category/product"
Как можно сделать отдельную страницу для каждой категории? 
НП: "/shop/category/" -все товары данное категории и потом "/shop/category/product" конкретный товар

Comment: По умолчанию так и есть - у каждой категории есть своя "страница" (она виртуальная)

Comment: Структуру изменена предыдущими  разработчиками.

Comment: сейчас у меня при переходе по /shop/category/ 404

Comment: На "category" и будет 404. А на "/category/слаг_категории/" будет страница с товарами из категории. (это при дефолтных правилах ЧПУ)

Comment: category в данном случае и есть "слаг_категории"

Comment: @IDL имеется ввиду "слаг_категории" слаг конкретной категории товаров (cars, wheels и тд).

Comment: да я понял, но структура шаблона изменено и то что было по умолчание сейчас не работает

Comment: Ну если в данном контексте употребляется "структура шаблона" , то нужно обращаться к специалисту по ВП.